# It possible align right to left item last row in grid view - flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have a grid view include items like this image:

[image]

In a grid view with 3 columns, normally the items in the grid view are arranged from left to right as shown in the image. Now, I want the last row to have items arranged from right to left when there is only 1 or 2 items, while when there are exactly 3 items, they should be arranged from left to right as usual. Can anyone guide me on how to achieve this? The code is provided below:

```
GridView.builder(
        itemCount: uploadFileResponseList.length,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: (uploadFileResponseList.length > 3)
              ? 3
              : uploadFileResponseList.length,
          crossAxisSpacing: 10.wr,
          mainAxisSpacing: 10.wr,
        ),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return CachedImageNetwork(
                    imageUrl: uploadFileResponseList[index].parsedUrl,
                    radius: 6.wr,
                  );
}
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you to use `Wrap`

demo code:

```
    Wrap(
      spacing: 10,
      runSpacing: 10,
      alignment: WrapAlignment.end,
      children: uploadFileResponseList.map((e) => SizedBox(
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        child: CachedImageNetwork(
          imageUrl: e.parsedUrl,
          radius: 6.wr,
        ),
      )).toList(),
    )
```

Comment: How to add crossAxisCount like Gridview to Wrap? I wanna 3 column like image.

Comment: can't add `crossAxisCount` to `Wrap`, so you need calculate `CachedImageNetwork` width and height by yourself @HuyNguyen

Comment: Tks a lot, i used Wrap and set height with LayoutBuilder and it work.